# Can I use javascript code to mimic a user click a link and the page goes to the linked page?

Tags: javascript

Can I use javascript code to mimic a user click a link and the page goes to the linked page? If so, how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: such a nasty website to not have control over what links you do not want to click! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `.click()` method on the link.

```
document.getElementById('the-id-of-the-element').click();
```